How Can I Generate a Localhost SSL Certificate for My Angular 17 Application?
I want to generate a localhost certificate for using SSL in my Angular 17 application. Angular provides SSL by configuring it in the devserver (Vite) with:
{
  "ssl": true,
  "sslKey": "./path_to_your_key.key",
  "sslCert": "./path_to_your_certificate.crt"
}

To generate the localhost key and certificate, I found a solution using mkcert. However, mkcert requires installation on every developer's computer, which is inconvenient, especially for those using Windows. Moreover, I have multiple projects that do not require HTTPS, so I prefer not to use mkcert.
Another solution suggested by ChatGPT involved running the following OpenSSL commands:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out localhost.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=Organization/OU=OrgUnit/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr -signkey localhost.key -out localhost.crt

I configured the generated files in my Angular application as follows:
{
  "ssl": true,
  "sslKey": "./localhost.key",
  "sslCert": "./localhost.crt"
}

However, when I opened the browser at https://localhost:4300, I encountered the error: "Your connection is not private."


I also found a gist here suggesting the following commands to create a RootCA:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -new -sha256 -days 1024 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout RootCA.key -out RootCA.pem -subj "/C=US/CN=Example-Root-CA"
openssl x509 -outform pem -in RootCA.pem -out RootCA.crt

After generating the RootCA files and setting them in Angular, I still encountered the same issue: "Your connection is not private."

I'm not sure what else needs to be done or how to resolve this issue. Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is all working like it is supposed to. You should not be able to get a trusted CA to issue a certificate with a hostname of 'localhost', and untrusted certificate chains will generate scary browser warnings. That and more is what it takes to have some semblance of secure network connections on the internet. You are already aware of the workarounds.

I've had to do the same thing today. After a bit of faffing around repeatedly installing and removing certificates, and with a bit of help from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWjVXb7-mSU and his corresponding git repo https://gist.github.com/arundhaj/d1ee3ca087208e843c4cff20a5d0a8df I was able to get an SSL certificate running on my Angular app (currently v18).
You will need to install / use OpenSSL to generate the certificate. I didn't have OpenSSL installed, however, having previously installed Git I found openssl.exe in the C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin folder.

To keep things simple I ran Powershell as an Administrator and navigated to the Git bin directory:

cd C:\"Program Files"\Git\usr\bin


Create a certificate.cnf file in this folder containing contents similar to the code below (taken and tweaked from the git repo I mentioned earlier). Feel free to change the Organisation details, but don't change the localhost settings:

[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C = UK
ST = United Kingdom
L = United Kingdom
O = My Organisation
OU = My Organisational Unit
emailAddress = email@domain.com
CN = localhost

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost


Generate a localhost.crt and localhost.key file with a 10 year expiration (which should suffice!) by running the following command in the same folder as the OpenSSL.exe and the newly created certificate.cnf file:

./openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3650 -out localhost.crt -config certificate.cnf


Move the localhost.crt and localhost.key files to your angular project. In my case I put them in a src\ssl folder. You can delete the certificate.cnf or put it somewhere for safekeeping if you need to repeat this process.

Modify the serve -> options section of the angular.json file to use ssl:


"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "ssl": true,
    "sslKey": "src/ssl/localhost.key",
    "sslCert": "src/ssl/localhost.crt"
  },
  ..etc


Launch Manage user certificates from the Windows start menu (type cert and select it from the results)
Go to Trusted Root Certification -> Certificates, right click on Certificates and then All Tasks -> Import. Browse for the localhost.crt file you moved into your Angular project, click next and make sure it will place the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certification store. Click next and finish.
Close any open browsers and run ng serve -o from your Angular app. It should now launch https://localhost:4200 without a certificate warning, HOWEVER, there is a strong possibility it will have cached your previous insecure certificate information, so if you are still seeing the warning make sure you clear the localhost site data by going to Developer Tools (F12) -> Application Tab -> Storage and click the Clear site data button. In my case, to demonstrate it was being cached I opened up a new incognito window and I was able to access https://localhost:4200 without a certificate warning, which proved I needed to clear the site data.

I hope this helps and is not too long. Only my third post on stack overflow so I probably need to work on my brevity!
